# ASP .NET Trying to Include MVC Assemblies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm compiling and publishing a ASP .NET 4.5 Web Application Project to an Azure Web Role. During the compilation and publish, I see the following warnings:

```
<WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
4><WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
4><WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
4><WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
4><WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
4><WebApp_Name>(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project '<WebApp_Name>' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
```

However, this app does not use MVC. Is there any way of getting rid of these warnings?

Thanks

Comment: While you might not be using MVC, you probably have a reference to these assemblies.